# Variable control for three iterations cicle for

Tags: java

I should create a program in which given a variable A, which I receive from a device every certain time. Variable A is a counter that goes from 0 to 32000.

I have to verify that at each iteration this variable actually gets incremented. In the event that, for three consecutive iterations, the value of variable A remains the same, I have to set a variable B to true to generate the alarm. Otherwise variable B must be false (no alarm) and set variable A_old = A.

Where A_old is the old value of variable A.

I can't figure out how to make such a program. I wrote this code, but I doubt it will work properly.

```
    int A = ValueToReciveDeviceEveryTime;
    int A_old = A;
    boolean B = false;   

 for (int i = 0; i<32000; i++)
    {
        int control = 0;
        if(A_old == A)
            control++;
            else
             control = 0;

        if (control == 3)
        {
            B = true;
        }
        else
        {
            B = false;
            A_old = A;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has the basic idea, but there are a few modifications to make in order to get it working correctly.

1. You should use braces `{}` to group multiple statements together for clarity and correctness, especially in the `if-else` conditions.
2. The loop you've written assumes that the value of `A` will increment automatically. In a real-world scenario, you'd likely need to update `A` by reading a new value from the device each iteration.
3. The variable `control` needs to be defined outside of the loop. If you define it inside the loop, it'll be re-initialized to 0 on every iteration, which isn't what you want.

Here's a corrected version of your code:

```java
int A = ValueToReciveDeviceEveryTime;  // Assuming this value is fetched somehow
int A_old = A;
boolean B = false;   
int control = 0;

// I've assumed you want to loop until an alarm is triggered. Adjust as needed.
while (B == false) { 
    if(A_old == A) {
        control++;
    } else {
        control = 0;
    }

    if (control == 3) {
        B = true;  // alarm condition
    } else {
        A_old = A;
    }

    A = getNewValueFromDevice();  // You'll need to implement this or something similar to update the value of A
}
```

You'll need to replace `getNewValueFromDevice()` with however you're reading the new value for `A` from the device.

This program will continue to loop until `B` becomes `true`, i.e., until the alarm condition is met. If you want to loop for a set number of iterations (like 32000 in your original code), you can replace the `while` loop with a `for` loop and check the value of `B` within the loop to break out early if needed.

to make it more tangible I defined getNewValueFromDevice method like a random generator number, so we can see some results and  `Thread.sleep(100);` is used because the code can get executed slower.

```
public class test {
      private static int control = 0;
        
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            int A = 10;  // Starting value
            int A_old = A;
            boolean B = false;

            while (!B) {  // Loop until B becomes true
                A = getNewValueFromDevice();
                
                if (A_old == A) {
                    control++;
                } else {
                    control = 0;
                }
                
                System.out.println("Current value: " + A + ", Previous value: " + A_old + ", Consecutive equals: " + control);
                
                if (control == 3) {
                    System.out.println("BINGO..... Alarm condition");
                    B = true;  // Alarm condition met
                } else {
                    A_old = A;
                }
                
                Thread.sleep(100);  // Sleep for 0.1 seconds  
            }
            
            System.out.println("End ....");
        }

        private static int getNewValueFromDevice() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int val = rand.nextInt(11);
            System.out.println("Rand value is " + val);
            return val;  // Return a random integer between 0 and 10 (inclusive)
        }
}
```

This picture is showing the result, of course you might have different values and it might take longer or shorter.
**The important thing is that the code stop exclusion when we have 3 consecutive equal values of A and A_old.**

[image]

Comment: @Kayamann it is better to mention what is wrong and why I wrote a mistaken answer, and I am not a Bot I am a real person who is trying to help someone!!!!!

Comment: @Kayaman I am, also, curious on how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: @Nicolas I could be mistaken, the output just seemed very robotic.

Comment: @Nicolas, I guess I have explained all, what part is not clear to you? ask me and I explain what I thought, this came to me based on what I got from the question. I though that the code must have a loop until there is an interruption which in this case as in the question control is equal to 3. The getNewValueFromDevice method might be something like a random generation number based on a timer or whatsoever to test

Comment: @Kayaman , and Nicolas,  I edited my response with the executed code and result. You shouldn't Judge people so soon. PS: Apologies Accepted

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I was hasty with my judgement.

Comment: @ShilaMosammami I was curious on why Kayaman came to the conclusion that you were a bot. It has nothing to do with your answer.

Comment: @Nicolas the answer resembled a common ChatGPT pattern, but in the comments, AI just can't generate that amount of sass.